# Mircorsoft graphi Api, The invitation was declined because it occurred in the past

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I have an application which sets up meeting using the microsoft Graph API. When the user updates the meeting end time and clicks end meeting, the meeting is auto declined and i get a message quote "The invitation was declined because it occurred in the past.".

Comment: Could you please describe what you would expect to happen.

Comment: When i end the meeting before time i donot want to get the declined mail from the resource room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The designed behavior of the Resource Booking Attendant is to decline
>   meetings that occur in the past.  The only option we can offer is to
>   disable the Resource Booking Attendant, so that appointments in the
>   past will show in the resource calendar as tentative.

So this is not a Graph API issue, but your mail server configure issue. Before you disable the Resource Booking Attendant in Exchange, you cannot so more for appointment item in the past. **If you don't have permission to configure the Exchange, redesign your app to limit user action on this.**